# How do I move Outlook emails to document folders and retain dates?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, move

I want to move some of my old outlook emails from outlook to my C Drive folders retaining the same date created, emailed, sent etc  properties. How can I do this?

Comment: How is everything going now? Have you found your answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you export the emails to a different format, or find a way to copy and paste them to a different format then these emails will have a new date. I do not think you can avoid that.

If you save them as Archive files, to later open in Outlook, then the emails will have the existing date they had in Outlook. I have lots of archives with the old dates.

Comment: Thank you, John. Good to know.

Comment: You might wish to acknowledge my answer if you have found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The message date is stored in the email message itself as the basic attribute of the mail information, which is different from the date in the file attributes. When you put those moved emails back into Outlook and open them, it can still display the original email time.

Sure, the Archive feature mentioned above  by John is a good way to manage old email messages, and the Outlook export feature can also work as well.